# Python Random BPF

Tags: python-3.x, function, random

I was working with the Python Random library, what does BPF mean, the simple print line is,

print(random.BPF)

What is the full form and what exactly does this mean.

Answer (score 1):

BPF - bits-per-float (should be 53)

Source: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/random.py